# Flutter Firestore NoSuchMethodError: The method 'get' was called on null

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore database. What I want to know is how to check if a certain Document reference exists in this database. The code I have used to work but now it's broken.

**Get reference**

```
travelTotalReference =
        Firestore.instance.document('$_id/$_presentDate BalanceTotal');
```

**check if data exists**

```
 travelTotalReference.get().then((dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists) {
          setState(() {
            travel = dataSnapshot.data['total'];
          });
        }else{
          setState(() {
            travel = 0;
          });
        }
      });
```

By the way I know for a fact that this Reference does not exists. I just want to make sure that if it does i can update the travel variable.

**The error I get**

```
E/flutter (17184): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: 
Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (17184): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'get' was called on null.
E/flutter (17184): Receiver: null
E/flutter (17184): Tried calling: get()
E/flutter (17184): #0      Object.noSuchMethod 
(dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:48:5)
```

Comment: Obviously `travelTotalReference` is `null` when you do not expect it to be. Your code in the question is missing the essential parts that would allow to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you call an object that doesn't exist, how can you expect your `travelTotalReference` to be anything but null.

Since then calling `get()` on it return an error, seems fair...